# My stopwatch is acting funny - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been going about this for a while. Whenever I click "start" more than once, it adds up. If you notice, if I click "start" twice, the counting on my clock starts to act funny :

```js
var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0],
  start = document.getElementById('start'),
  stop = document.getElementById('stop'),
  clear = document.getElementById('clear'),
  seconds = 0,
  minutes = 0,
  GG;

function add() {
  seconds++;
  if (seconds >= 60) {
    seconds = 0;
    minutes++;
    if (minutes >= 60) {
      minutes = 0;
    }
  }

  h1.textContent =
    (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) : "00") +
    ":" + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds);

  timer();
}

function timer() {
  GG = setTimeout(add, 1000);
}
timer();


start.onclick = timer;

stop.onclick = function() {
  clearTimeout(GG);
}

clear.onclick = function() {
  h1.textContent = "00:00";
  seconds = 0;
  minutes = 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="time-container">
    <h1><time>00:00</time></h1>
    <button id="start">start</button>
    <button id="stop">stop</button>
    <button id="clear">clear</button>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I have to press STOP , N times as many as START.
If I want to fix this, to make any succeeding presses to START will not matter. Only one counting execution will be running at any time.

Comment: Set a Flag... flag = true;... Inside your funct > if(flag) do the func and set flag to false, else dont do anything.

Comment: Clarify what you mean by 'the function seems to add more and more'. What is happening and what do you want it to do?

Comment: Nothing in the code you have posted would cause the function to run even once. Where is the rest of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a variable to check click on `start`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    
</head>

<body>
    <div class="time-container">
        <h1><time>00:00</time></h1>
        <button id="start">start</button>
        <button id="stop">stop</button>
        <button id="clear">clear</button>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0]
        , start = document.getElementById('start')
        , stop = document.getElementById('stop')
        , clear = document.getElementById('clear')
        , seconds = 0
        , minutes = 0
        , GG
        , flag = true;

    function add() {
        seconds++;
        if (seconds >= 60) {
            seconds = 0;
            minutes++;
            if (minutes >= 60) {
                minutes = 0;
            }
        }
        h1.textContent = (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) : "00") + ":" + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds);
        timer();
    }

    function timer() {
        GG = setTimeout(add, 1000);
    }
    start.onclick = function () {
        if(flag)
            {
                timer();
                flag = false;
            }
    }
    stop.onclick = function () {
        clearTimeout(GG);
        flag = true;
    }
    clear.onclick = function () {
        h1.textContent = "00:00";
        seconds = 0;
        minutes = 0;
    }
</script>
</html>
```